# PHP: why do these output different results?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I built two versions of a PHP 7 function that takes an array, and returns a list of arrays showing all the permutations of the original array members. For instance, for input `[1,2,3]`, the expected output would be all six permutations of 1, 2, and 3.

I expected both versions of the function to give the same output but can't figure out why they don't.  Here is the first (works as expected):

```
function permutations(array $input): array {
  $func = function (array $selected, array $chooseFrom, array &$results) 
             use (&$func) {

    foreach ($chooseFrom as $k => $unchosen):
      $selectedCopy = $selected; // make a copy
      $chooseFromCopy = $chooseFrom; // make a copy

      $selectedCopy[] = $unchosen; // add the next unchosen item to selected list
      array_splice($chooseFromCopy, $k,1); // remove the item from chooseFrom list
      $func($selectedCopy, $chooseFromCopy, $results); // recursive call
    endforeach;

    // If we've used all items. Add selection to results
    if (empty($chooseFrom)) $results[] = $selected;
  };

  $results = [];
  $func([], $input, $results);
  return $results;
}
```

When I call [`permutations([1,2])`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5822a1fe506bf0f2c8ed89f28ef8a6f19dc5645f) I get the expected result: `[[1,2],[2,1]]`.

Here is the non-working version of the function. The only difference is in the `foreach`:

```
function permutations2(array $input): array {

  $func = function (array $selected, array $chooseFrom, array &$results) 
             use (&$func) {

    foreach ($chooseFrom as $k => $unchosen):    
      $chooseFromCopy = $chooseFrom; // make a copy

      $selected[] = $unchosen; // add the next unchosen to the selected list
      array_splice($chooseFromCopy, $k, 1); // remove the item from chooseFrom list
      $func($selected, $chooseFromCopy, $results); // recursive call
    endforeach;

    // If we've used all items. Add selection to results
    if (empty($chooseFrom)) $results[] = $selected;
  };

  $results = [];
  $func([], $input, $results);
  return $results;
}
```

When I call [`permutations2([1,2])`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/166f89723263cfd4f8bb86214f3c62de0c92ae89) I get a bad result: `[[1,2],[1,2,1]]`

Why is there a difference??

Comment: The problem is about the variable "$selected" holding the results of the first iteration of the first for loop and it needs to be cleared before going into the next iteration of the loop.  Adding the line "$selected = array();" before endforeach statement will make the code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about the variable "$selected" holding the results of the first iteration of the for loop and it needs to be reinitialized before going into the next iteration of the loop. Storing the "$selected" in another variable ( let's say $tempselected) before the for loop and reinitializing "$selected" variable with   $tempselected before endforeach statement will make the code work.  But this changes is almost same as the working sample of the function :)

```
<?php

function permutations2(array $input): array {

  $func = function (array $selected, array $chooseFrom, array &$results) 
             use (&$func) {
    $selectedTemp = $selected;

    foreach ($chooseFrom as $k => $unchosen):    
      $chooseFromCopy = $chooseFrom; // make a copy

      $selected[] = $unchosen; // add the next unchosen to the selected list
      array_splice($chooseFromCopy, $k, 1); // remove the item from chooseFrom list
      $func($selected, $chooseFromCopy, $results); // recursive call
      $selected = $selectedTemp;
    endforeach;

    echo("<br>After For Loop <br>");
    // If we've used all items. Add selection to results
      if (empty($chooseFrom))  { $results[] = $selected;  }  
  };

  $results = [];
  $func([], $input, $results);
  return $results;
}
$res = permutations2(['a','b','c']);
```

Comment: Just tested with more type of input values-  Clearing also doesn't help if input array size is more than 2.   Checking to see if there is any simple way to fix this other than the first version of the function.